# function returning [object Object] on request nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have a function in my auth.js file, in which I export and call the values through my get request in my index.js file. I then use this file to pass the data to the front end, but what is happening is, I am returning a boolean in auth.js and then exporting the entire function and importing it through index.js, but the boolean is not being passed. I've attached the code below
auth.js

```
const adminCheck = async (req, res, callback) => {
console.log("one")
await UtilRole.roleCheck(req, res, 'ADMIN', (response) =>  { 
    if(response) {
        console.log("one: true")
         return true
     } else {
        console.log("one: false")
        return false
        //  return callback(null, false)
     }
 })
}

module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated,
    roleCheck,
    adminCheck
}
```

index.js

```
  router.get('/viewRegistration', auth.ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    var role = auth.adminCheck(req, res);
  

  const user = JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user)
  var query =  "SELECT * FROM tkwdottawa WHERE email = '" + user.emailAddress + "'";
    console.log("EMAIL ADDRESS user.emailAddress: " + user.emailAddress)
  
    ibmdb.open(DBCredentials.getDBCredentials(), function (err, conn) {
      if (err) return res.send('sorry, were unable to establish a connection to the database. Please try again later.');
      conn.query(query, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) { 
        Response.writeHead(404);
      }
      
    
       res.render('viewRegistration',{page_title:"viewRegistration",data:rows, user, role: role});
        
      conn.close(function () {
        console.log('closed /viewRegistration');
        
      });
      });
    });
  //res.render('viewRegistration', { title: 'Express', user });
});
```

this returns `[object Object]`

any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Comment: mind [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: `adminCheck` does not contain any `return`-statements. At all. But since the function is `async` it's implicitely returning `Promise.resolve(undefined)`. That's your object.

Comment: @Thomas so how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

It means you are alerting an instance of an object. When alerting the object, `toString()` is called on the object, and the default implementation returns `[object Object]`.

```
var objA = {};
var objB = new Object;
var objC = {};

objC.toString = function () { return "objC" };

alert(objA); // [object Object]
alert(objB); // [object Object]
alert(objC); // objC
```

If you want to inspect the object, you should either `console.log` it, `JSON.stringify()` it, or enumerate over it's properties and inspect them individually using for in.

```
console.log("EMAIL ADDRESS user.emailAddress: " + JSON.stringify(user.emailAddress))
```

Comment: when I tried this, I did `console.log("role: " + JSON.stringify(role))`, and it gave `role: {}`

Comment: It looks like your object is empty, then. `JSON.stringify(role)` seems to have worked for you here, now that you can see the object, so you should now focus on why your `role` is an empty object.